# libgdx can't start desktop project on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, libgdx, lwjgl

so, I just created libgdx project for desktop and imported it (gradle) to eclipse. When I launch it this error pops up:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:446)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:954)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
... 2 more
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

I can't figure out what's happening. Project's created for android and launched in android studio working properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the xorg-xrandr package, see

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18801

Answer (score 6):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2743), try to install xorg-xrandr.

Also, I fixed this issue by installing [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Answer (score 1):

This error disappeared for me after I switched from the default lwjgl backend (that is for some reason still used in the tool to generate a LibGDX project) to lwjgl3 backend. This is how you do it for a project freshly generated with gdx-setup.jar ([doc](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle)):

In `build.gradle` change

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
```

to

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
```

In `DesktopLauncher` class, change

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
```

to

```
Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
new Lwjgl3Application(new Game(), config);
```

and modify imports to

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
```

so basically just add `3` after `lwjgl` in those two places.