# LibGDX project isn't launching, it says Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.Sys

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, libgdx

Whenever I try to launch a LibGDX project, the problem shown below keeps appearing:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 577 ms
> Task :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()
[LwjglApplication] Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libgdxalice/dd5c1a65/liblwjgl64.so: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /tmp/libgdxalice/dd5c1a65/liblwjgl64.so)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALLwjglAudio.<init>(OpenALLwjglAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.createAudio(LwjglApplication.java:282)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:71)
    at com.kuuject.atherwund.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:10)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.Sys
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:643)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:125)
9:18:30 AM: Execution finished ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the solution. At first, I tried reinstalling my JDK, but that wasn't the issue at all. It wasn't an issue before I switched to PopOS. Any help?

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError with the message "Could not initialize class ....." says that at that point the JVM has already tried and failed to perform static initialization on the named class.  You may get a different message the first time the JVM tries to initialize the class. Can you see a different message at the start of the error output?  If so, please edit the question to include this.

Comment: I included it now

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra detail to your question.  I have to admit I'm no expert on libgdx or LWJGL: I don't think I've ever used either of them before and certainly haven't seen that error before.  However, you now have an error message that gives more information about the problem, so hopefully someone who knows more about these things will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. You need to change the LWJGL api in build.gradle, dependencies to LWJGL3.

```
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
```

to

```
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
```

In DesktopLauncher.java, change these

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
```

and

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
```

to

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
```

and

```
Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
new Lwjgl3Application(new MyGdxGame(), config);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with LWJGL not LibGDX for *nix. Follow the instructions here

[libgdx can't start desktop project on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277482/libgdx-cant-start-desktop-project-on-ubuntu)